# microsoft windows driver kit pure C try catch syntax?

Tags: c, try-catch, wdk

In the [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/wdkpkg.mspx) there are some driver code samples written in pure C, but sprinkled with some try-catch-finally constructs. Does someone know their semantics ? Thank you microsoft for your great tools and standards compliance.

Code extract from `some_file.c`:

```
try {
    ...
    if (!NT_SUCCESS( status )) {

       leave; // ???
    }
    ...
} finally {
    ...
}

try  {
    ...
} except( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: -1 for uninformed MS bashing -- SEH was needed and, aside from predating C++ exceptions, implements a model which some find superior to C++.  Certainly for writing device drivers and kernel, your reaction to it is troubling.  Wanting to use C++ exception handling in a driver is suspect.

Comment: +1 to cancel -1 given by MS fanboy

Comment: Every OS has its extensions to ISO C, for instance asprintf() and epoll(). You just have to discover and get used to them. I'm quite sure MS does not have EXPORT_SYMBOL() as well. Each kernel defines its own sandbox, may as well get used to that :) Working in kernel space, or if using a microkernel driver space comes with its own set of rules. No kernel that I know of facilitates an ISO standard C library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The try/except handling in the WDK follows the SEH model used throughout windows. Notice that you can continue after catching an exception.

This model predated C++, so the C++ standard is not the same as the exception model used by Win32.

PS: C does not have exception handling, so SEH is a non-standard extension to C.

[SEH exception handling in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[Introduction to SEH](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/Exception/Exception.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Despite looking like C++ keywords, those are actually macros for SEH exception handling.

Add these do your preprocessor definitions:

```
try=__try
except=__except
finally=__finally
leave=__leave
```